# HTML div filter with jQuery and CSS class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the below filters wich is filering some divs in my page
At this time its working, bt i have lots of product categories that needs to be filtered and i dont want to write them all in the html. 
Please check below to understand better.

Filters HTML

```
 <div id="stick-filter" class="filters panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-content">
      <ul class="check-square filters-option">
        <li data-id="alfa 1,alfa 2,beta 1,beta 2" data-filter="stick"> <a href="#">All<small class="total"></small></a></li>
        <li data-id="alfa 1,alfa 2" data-filter="stick"> <a href="#">Alfa<small class="total-al"></small></a></li>
        <li data-id="beta 1,beta 2" data-filter="stick"> <a href="#">Beta<small class="total-be"></small></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Filtered divs:

```
<div class="product-list">
<div id="product-list"  class="row image-box product listing-style1"> 
  <div data-stick="beta 1" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Beta 1</p></div>
  <div data-stick="beta 2" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>Beta 2</p></div>
  <div data-stick="alfa 1" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>alfa 1</p></div>
  <div data-stick="alfa 2" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><p>alfa 2</p></div>
</div>
```

And jQuery code is

```
//filters
$(".filters li").on("click", function () {
    id = ($(this).data("id")+'').split(',');
    filter = $(this).data("filter");
    $("#product-list .col-sm-6").hide();
    id[0] == "all" && $("#product-list .col-sm-6").show() || id.forEach(function(v){
        $('#product-list .col-sm-6[data-'+filter+'="'+v.trim()+'"]').show();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Is there a way to change my filters action as below to avoid writing all the products categories in the li data-id field.

```
<li data-id="**to show all the products**" data-filter="stick"> <a href="#">All<small class="total"></small></a></li>
<li data-id="**where the word alfa is found**" data-filter="stick"> <a href="#">Alfa<small class="total-al"></small></a></li>
<li data-id="**where the word beta is found**" data-filter="stick"> <a href="#">Beta<small class="total-be"></small></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery's `.filter()` method, like this:

```
var id = 'example';

$('#product-list .col-sm-6')
    .filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('id').indexOf(id) >= 0;
    })
    .show();
```

In this example, all list elements with `data-id` **containing** `example` phrase will be shown.

Comment: and on the li filters ?

Comment: Do you want them all to *search* value instead of *check*?

Comment: @I want when i select the Alfa li to show up all the divs that contain the alfa in data-stick